# Can't create a simple CDF

Tags: cdf-format

I decided it was time I investigated CDFs, so I created the following simple `Manipulate` using Mathematica version 9.0.1.0:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}
  ],
 {a, 1, 10},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: simple manipulate]

Then I selected File>CDF Preview>CDF Player

[image: file cdf preview]

which produced a new window:

[image: cdf preview]

Not very interesting (a bit like yesterday's paper — flat, lifeless, inactive), but perhaps that's what it's supposed to look like at this point. I pressed on, and used the wizard (File>CDF Export>Standalone...) to save a CDF version of the notebook.

[image: cdf wizard]

I put the new CDF file in a trusted directory, then opened the Wolfram CDF Player (version 9.0.1.0) and tried to open the file. Nothing happened - no console messages. I know that the CDF Player works, because I can open CDFs downloaded from [demonstrations.wolfram.com](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com).

The CDF file itself can be opened in *Mathematica* and works as expected. I tried opening it in CDF player with *Mathematica* running, and also after quitting *Mathematica*. I also tried with CDFs made using File>SaveAs... -> CDF.

I've read the CDF-tagged questions here, but can't find anything that addresses my basic inability to create a simple CDF.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. Everything works ok on WinXp MMA 9.0.1.0 nad on CDFPlayer 9.0.1.0. What if you try to create a CDF with only the output cell with current selection marked in Step 2of deploynment process?

Comment: @kuba - I did wonder whether my installation had gone awry somehow. If it works for everyone else, I'll have to re-install. (Current selection didn't work either.)

Comment: After CDF Preview, I got it working in a MS Surface Pro. Before you reinstall your Mathematica license on your Mac, you might be interested in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29809/mathematica-performance-on-mac.

Comment: @hector :) Nice try, Steve Ballmer!

Comment: Have you altered the default stylesheet?  It looks like there's an opener for your input cell that I don't see by default in a windows version.

Comment: @bobthechemist Hmm, I'll investigate that...

Comment: @bobthechemist doesn't matter, at least on win, I have openers enabled too.

Comment: @Kuba I agree, I had checked that as well, but I wonder if some subtle changes to the stylesheet are forcing the dynamics to not be enabled (or even the button to enable dynamics to be presented).

Comment: I just tried on MacOSX 10.8.4, using v9.0.1, looking all fine here. (no openers enabled here)

Comment: @PinguinDirk OK, thanks. Looks like I have an installation problem. Will re-install later and see what happens...

Comment: I have the same problem on v8.0.4, but FileOutlineCache makes no difference

Comment: @ssch see if it works after moving your init.m file somewhere else. Perhaps there's another setting in there which has the same effect.

Comment: @carmullion Thanks, that did it. Now I get the "Enable dynamic content" box when I open the cdf. I'll hunt around a bit until I find the setting that broke it

Comment: @cormullion, turns out it was the "WindowFrame"->"Generic" option that hides the dynamic notification :/

Comment: @ssch strange...looks like the CDF code needs to check for some of these options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traced the problem to this line in my `init.m`:

```
PrivateNotebookOptions->{"FileOutlineCache"->False,
```

I'm not sure how it got set to false, probably me fiddling with some options one day, but once it's set to `True` it's possible to create CDFs in the usual way.

Comment: May I ask how have you traced it?

Comment: @kuba Removed the support folder, it worked, so replaced it. Removed init.m, it worked, so replaced it. Then a binary split test - remove half the file, if it works, then the problem is in the other half; repeat until the problem is isolated. Only took 1/2 hour :)